# Allow multiple instances of reCAPTCHA on the same page

Tags: 7, captcha

There are several forms in a page and I use [recaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha) module for all of them. The problem is, the recaptcha is generated for one of them not all of them.

[In Allow multiple instances of reCAPTCHA on the same page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1833822) the [recaptcha-mutltiple_instances-1833822-31.patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/recaptcha-mutltiple_instances-1833822-31.patch) patch is offered, and sounds it is working (I am not sure). But the problem is the `recaptcha.js` file doesn't exist in the recaptha module folder while it asks to update that file as well.

This is the module folder:

[image]

Comment: Apply this patch https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/recaptcha-mutltiple_instances-1833822-31.patch

Comment: @Adi I already mentioned this patch in the question.

Comment: You got message to update jqeury or something else?

Comment: No, I just installed that module. The problem is `recaptcha.js` doesn't exist at all

Comment: they are using external js to include with for example https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js which is same equivalent to recaptcha.js

Comment: So, what I shall I do? I can't update a file on Google server!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was first open for the developer version 7.x-1.x-dev, which contains that file; then it was updated for 8.x-2.x-dev, and then 7.x-2.x-dev. You need to install the developer version, and apply the patch for that developer version.

Comment: You mean the `7.x-1.12` version which has yellow background color or `7.x-2.x-dev` which has red background color?

Comment: Patch are always submitted for the development snapshot; in this case, the issue was first open for the 7.x-1.x-dev version.

Comment: I saw I forgot the -dev part in the version ID.